# Weird code added to the custom function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wrote this code below in order to show first 3 blog posts on my top page in wordpress.

```
function wptuts_recentpost($atts, $content=null){
$getpost = get_posts( array('number' => 1) );
$getpost = $getpost[0];
$return =  "<img src=" . get_the_post_thumbnail($getpost->ID) . " >" . "<br />" . $getpost->post_title . "<br />" . $getpost->post_excerpt . "…";
$return .= "<br /><br /><a href='" . get_permalink($getpost->ID) . " style='color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgb(117, 172, 255); font-size: 18px; margin: 10px; width: 162px;' class='edgtf-btn edgtf-btn-large edgtf-btn-solid edgtf-btn-custom-hover-bg edgtf-direction-aware-hover'><span class='edgtf-btn-text-holder'><span class='edgtf-btn-text'>read more →</span><div class='edgtf-btn-background-holder'>
        <span class='edgtf-btn-background' style='background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); top: 30px; left: 65px;'></span>
   </div></a>";
return $return;
}
add_shortcode('newestpost', 'wptuts_recentpost');
```

This code used to work fine, but when I recently checked again, permalink this code provided wrong link (partly correct but it adds '%20style=' at the end).

How could I fix this so that it gives me the right link.

Comment: "style **Remove the space before style**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line:

```
$return .= "<br /><br /><a href='" . get_permalink($getpost->ID) . " style='color:
```

You haven't put the closing `'` for the `href`:

```
$return .= "<br /><br /><a href='" . get_permalink($getpost->ID) . "' style='color:
```

Because you haven't put the closing `'`, the `href` interpret the opening `'` of the `style` as its closing `'`. Therefore you got `%20style=` at the end of your permalink.
Just giving the closing `'` for your `href` should already solve your problem.

Comment: Silly me... Thank you for your quick answer! problem solved!